# How to retrieve user data from MYSQL?

Tags: android

I'm making an android application through Android Studio and I want to retrieve user details from a **MYSQL** database and display these details in different text views. So what are the possible ways to do the same?

I have attached my php code. I want to use the JSON array data and display it in text views.

```html
<?php


$db_name="society_management";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$mail = $_POST['Email'];

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);




$sql = "select * from member;";


$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

array_push($result,aaray(
"mid"=>$row[0],
"nm"=>$row[1],
"hsno"=>$row[2],
"sts"=>$row[3],
"email"=>$row[4],
"mno"=>$row[5]
));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You can get data in android by making webservice using get, post methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create web-service at server side that must return json response of Sql data you requires.

For calling that service from android code and display to textview can be easily achieved by Retrofit lib. That automatically parse json data to Java Model.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use web services , Here is a good example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

Create a web-service at the server side which should return data in JSON format.
We can access data from the server by using either of the 3 ways in our android application :

1. Using Async task
2. Using Volly library
3. Using Retrofit